# Assembling helical antenna in production

Tags: antenna, soldering, production

How is small PCB mounted helical antennas (100 MHz - 1 GHz) assembled in PCB production? See picture below.

[image: Small helical antenna]

I have thought about mounting it both horizontally and vertically, but I can not figure out a process that does not require and abundant load of work done by hand. I plan on producing the PCBs in the thousands. How are these usually mounted and assembled in a factory? Why does almost all antennas include the 90 degree bend at the end? Is it supposed to be mounted in a hole or surface mounted on a pad? How are the antennas kept in place in the assembly and hand/selective soldering process? Is there any special considerations when designing a cutout in the PCB? The questions are many, the answers are few.

Comment: Supplier/product dependent - find one you want to use and link to the data sheet.

Comment: You should visit a factory in China, it is very informative. You'll see that a lot of specific production steps are actually made by hand, even for volumes of several thousands. For example, if there is a single PTH connector on a mostly-SMT board, they won't setup wave soldering. They will prefer soldering the connector by hand, which is actually cheaper. A single guy can probably solder one part on a thousand board in a single day. Given the wages in China, this shouldn't be a show-stopper.